# solve for x: $2x(4-x)^\frac{-1}2 -3\sqrt{4-x} = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

solve for x: $$2x(4-x)^\frac{-1}2  -3\sqrt{4-x} = 0$$

I started out by pulling a 2 from the right sided $\sqrt4$ to make it "$-6\sqrt{-x}$"

then I get lost on the left side, I'm pretty sure I can't have a negative square.

Comment: $-3\sqrt{4-x}\neq-6\sqrt{-x}$. You can only "pull out" a factor when it multiplies everything else under the root. For example, $\sqrt{4-4x}=\sqrt{4(1-x)}=\sqrt{4}\sqrt{1-x}=2\sqrt{1-x}$.

Answer (score 5):

One rule of exponents is that $x^{-a} = 1/x^a,$ so you can rewrite this as:

$$\frac{2x}{\sqrt{4-x}} - 3\sqrt{4-x} = 0.$$

Now multiply both sides by $\sqrt{4-x}$ and you're well on your way:

$$\frac{2x}{\sqrt{4-x}} - 3\sqrt{4-x} = 0$$
$$\sqrt{4-x}\left[\frac{2x}{\sqrt{4-x}} - 3\sqrt{4-x}\right] = \left(\sqrt{4-x}\right)\left[0\right]$$
$$\frac{2x\sqrt{4-x}}{\sqrt{4-x}} - 3\left(\sqrt{4-x}\right)^2 = 0$$
$$2x - 3(4-x) = 0$$
$$x = \frac{12}{5}.$$

Note: Another rule of exponents that's useful (and was used above) is that

$$x^{a/b} = \sqrt[b]{x^a}.$$

Comment: it didn't occur to me that if I made the left side a square root, that it would make it a fraction with 2x on top. thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.  Also note that $x^{1/a} = \sqrt[a]{x}.$

Comment: Hey John, I still can't seem to get the equation right. I do what you show here, I then get the right side to be $$\frac{-3(4-x)}\sqrt{4-x}}$$ I can't seem to get rid of the bottom square roots. I know I could flip them to be back with the negative 1/2 but I don't see the point in that.

Comment: The key part is "multiply both sides by $\sqrt{4-x}$".  Doing this gets rid of of the square root in the denominator of the first term on the left side.

Comment: but doesn't that add it to the right side since its now $$\frac{-3x(4-x)}{\sqrt{4-x}}$$ since it started out as $$\frac{-3x(4-x)}{1}$$ Wouldn't I be stuck with it on the right side?

Comment: is it because I'm not multiplying both sides by  $$\frac{\sqrt{4-x}}{\sqrt{4-x}}$$ but actually $$\frac{\sqrt{4-x}}{1}$$

Comment: Multiply both sides by $\sqrt{4-x}$, not $\sqrt{4-x}/\sqrt{4-x}$.  You won't be stuck with anything on the right side -- literally *and* figuratively -- because the right side is zero.

Comment: I added intermediate steps.

Comment: thank you very much for helping. I get frustrated and use the wrong steps. For some reason its stuck in my head to use the sqrt/sqrt when removing the radicals from fractions. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

I assumed that we have this one $$\frac{2x}{\sqrt{4-x}}  -3\sqrt{4-x} = 0$$ Now set $\sqrt{4-x}=t, ~~x< 4$ and then by plugging it we get this new version $$\frac{8-2t^2}{t}-3t=0$$ which is easy to solve.